# How do you make ggplot plots of numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, ggplot2

I know how to use ggplot for data frames, but is there a good way to make plots from numpy arrays directly? Or do I have to convert?

Comment: The problem is that this conflicts with the point of `ggplot`. Unlike regular plottling libraries like `matplotlib`, ggplot is based on the `Grammer of Graphics` - a formal description of what a plot actually is and how it can be composed from the data. `ggplot` is not meant to be a collection of plotting routines that get some arrays as input and produce a fancy plot. Regular plotting libraries are more suited for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to plot things in a "`ggplot`-like style", you can use the `matplotlib.style` package:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

# use ggplot style sheet
style.use('ggplot')

plt.plot(np.random.randn(10))
```

[image]

Of course (as cel pointed out), with matplotlib it's still up to you to make sure your plots actually follow the conventions set out in Grammar of Graphics.